# Revealing a Modal in Foundation 4

Tags: zurb-foundation

How do you Reveal a modal programmatically in Foundation 4?

In Foundation 3 we had the easy to use reveal() method.

What can you use in Foundation 4? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure you can simply use the .foundation method on your modal to call 'open' on it.. Something like:

`$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');`

e: Just checked the docs and yep, It's right there: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

Look for "You can also open and close Reveal via JavaScript:"

Comment: I wasn't able to get the modal to close with this method (either by clicking the close button or the reveal background). You can work around this by handling the click event on the button and calling 

    $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');

Comment: I cannot close the modal with 
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');

Comment: Same problem- closing via $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'close'); does only sometimes work.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in Foundation 4 you must have this trigger link to open a modal =/ Unfortunately not because you'll have to write a lot more code (thats not true), but because this implementation isnt, let's say, pretty.

My code for the modal:

```
<!-- MODAL BOX START CONFIGURATION -->
<a class="reveal-link" data-reveal-id="modal"></a>
<div id="modal" class="reveal-modal medium">
    <div id="modalContent"></div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

JS function to open and put some content into the modal

```
function openModal(url,params,text){

// If @url is not empty then we change the #modalContent value with the @url value
if(url !== '')
{
    ajaxLoad('#modalContent',url,params);
}
// If @text is not empty then we change the #modalContent value with the @text value
else if(text !== '')
{
    $('#modalContent').html(text);
}

// If both @url and @text are empty, then the #modalContent remains unchanged. 
// Now we just show de modal with the changed (or not) content
$('a.reveal-link').trigger('click'); }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For programmatic (javascript) access the [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) seem to only suggest launching via click event.

Add your Modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
  <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
  <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Set the trigger:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" id="my-trigger">Click Me For A Modal</a>
```

Activate trigger programmatically:

```
$('#my-trigger').trigger('click');
```

Admittedly it does seem like a work-around, maybe this is due to their heightened "lightweight/mobile-first" focus. Lets see what the next release brings.

Comment: I tried the code above but it does not work. Can you confirm it works for you?

Comment: I found one solution - that is to replace the a href with a <div>. Then it works. Could this be a bug?

Comment: The above works fine for me, using a fresh build of version 4 (make sure to include zepto.js and foundation.js above the alert plugin). Also, you may use just about any element you wish for the trigger (div, span, a, p etc.), as long as you give it the data-reveal-id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myModal").foundation('reveal', 'open');
```