# Zurb Foundation 4 Reveal Modal: Won't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 4.3.1 with Reveal 4.3.2 and jQuery 2.0.3.  I'm successfully opening a modal programmatically with the following code:

```
$('.akita-modal-ajax').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var modalId = $(this).data('id'),
        url = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#' + modalId).foundation('reveal', 'open', {
        url: url;
    });
});
```

The code I'm using to attempt to close the modal is:

```
$('.akita-modal').on('click', '.close-reveal-modal',function () {
    console.log('click');
    $('.akita-modal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
});
```

And my modal (once opened):

```
<div id="myModal" class="akita-modal open" style="display: block; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; top: 50px;">
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">×</a>
    ...More content...
</div>
```

When I click to close the modal it registers the 'click' in the console but the modal remains open.  Interestingly, if I ignore my custom classes and revert all references of 'akita-modal' back to 'reveal-modal' everything works as it should.  But then I'm stuck with Reveal's default styles.

I have also tried:

```
$('.akita-modal').on('opened', function () {
    $('.akita-modal').on('click', '.close-reveal-modal',function () {
        console.log('click');
        $('.akita-modal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
    });
});
```

With the exact same result.  The 'click' gets logged but the modal remains open.  I have no other errors in my console, and I haven't come across anyone else with this issue other than maybe JoelCDoyle in response to another SO question: [Revealing a Modal in Foundation 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245966/revealing-a-modal-in-foundation-4)

How can I get this modal to close using my own class names?

Comment: I'm having trouble returning control to the parent view when the modal is closed.  Perhaps you can help me.  My question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49161370/1735836

Answer (score 3):

Usually I use the modal Id to close it, like this :

```
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
```

And it works, so maybe it's a problem with using class names instead of IDs...?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it can occur when you forget attribute 'data-reveal'.
That's how it should be written:

```
<div class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
...
</div>
```